# IOS system sounds with custom audio sessions

Tags: ios, keyboard, audio, avaudiosession

I have an iOS application that plays different audio effects and records audio at the same time. The purpose of the application is currently not important, but I'm having problems with stock iOS audio effects.

To play the effects, I use `SimpleAudioEngine` from `CocosDenshion` API (which uses `AVAudioPlayer`, as far as I can see). The effects are preloaded and they work fine (I actually play them on buttons, scrolling and similar). Effects are played with the following code:

In `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"sound.wav"];
```

In other methods when playing is required:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"sound.wav"];
```

No wonders here, but at the same time, I am recording noise from the built-in microphone with `AVCaptureSession` API. The capture session code is from one of the examples found on the web.

```
AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

NSError *error = nil;
captureAudioDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:&error];

if ([captureSession canAddInput: captureAudioDeviceInput])
{
    [captureSession addInput:captureAudioDeviceInput];
}

captureAudioDataOutput = [AVCaptureAudioDataOutput new];

if ([captureSession canAddOutput:captureAudioDataOutput])
{
    [captureSession addOutput:captureAudioDataOutput];
}

// Create a serial dispatch queue and set it on the AVCaptureAudioDataOutput object
dispatch_queue_t audioDataOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("AudioDataOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

[captureAudioDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:audioDataOutputQueue];
dispatch_release(audioDataOutputQueue);

[captureSession startRunning];
```

Both parts of the code are working flawlessly one by one. **But when they are both activated at the same time, one of them breaks the other.** For example: the microphone is reading data without a problem, until one sound effect is played. I found a way around this, to activate `mixWithOthers` category, which is done with the following code:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: nil];
UInt32 doSetProperty = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(doSetProperty), &doSetProperty);
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

This is done before creating the `AVCaptureDevice` and `AVCaptureSession`.
The application works like it should, sounds are played and microphone reads the data. Hardware buttons are also working on the `CocosDenshion SimpleAudioEngine` (mute and volume).

But apparently, the application has a bug.

**When mute is disabled and application is playing sounds, the iOS keyboard clicking sounds on TextField are not played.** I want the clicking sounds to play.

I have debugged the code a bit and apparently it has something to do with **Audio session settings**. If I set the category to `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient`, the clicking sounds are played, but at very low volume (*the volume is maxed out and application sounds play out at max volume just nicely*). **And it gives another problem, SoloAmbient cancels my CaptureSession, which is understandable.**

I am testing the application on iPhone 5, but the same thing happens on the simulator too.

**So, what am I doing wrong with settings? How could I fix the settings so I keep all my audio sessions active and keep the iOS system sounds?**

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried setting the category to PlayAndRecord? If you want to play and record at the same time, you'll need to do it.

Comment: I have tried that before asking the question. The PlayAndRecord category makes the sounds play at a lower volume, but it does **not** bring back the missing keyboard sounds.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680503/how-to-get-the-audio-level-of-the-microphone-without-disabling-system-sounds

There are no answers unfortunately.  System sounds are disabled by default when recording is taking place.  I expect this is to prevent them being recorded by mistake, which under most circumstances would be what you would want.

You could implement the [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) protocol and play your own click every time `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` is called, perhaps.

Comment: Good point, I must say. However I want the clicks to be played. I already implemented the workaround you suggested, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: The link you have above to check out your question is broken.